# REST APIでレスポンスヘッダーの「strict-transport-security」を扱う方法について

Tags: c#, https, rest

現在、.Net(C#)でREST APIを開発しております。
ユーザーより、「レスポンスヘッダーに「strict-transport-security」を指定すること」と
仕様要求が上がったので、調べたのですが、REST APIにおいて「strict-transport-security」は
必要なレスポンスヘッダーなのでしょうか。

まだREST APIの開発経験がないため、このような質問で大変恐縮なのですが、
ご教授の程、よろしくお願い致します。

また、「strict-transport-security」は、クライアント側で指定する必要がある
ヘッダー情報なのか、サーバー側で設定する必要があるヘッダー情報かも併せてご教授頂ける幸いです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるようです。[Strict-Transport-Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security), [HSTS – HTTP Strict Transport Securityの使い方](https://kinsta.com/jp/knowledgebase/hsts-strict-transport-security/), [HSTS（HTTP STRICT TRANSPORT SECURITY）について詳細、設定方法を解説します](https://www.leon-tec.co.jp/blog/diary/9265/), [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。大変参考になりました。お忙しいところありがとうございました。